# What is wrong with my code - It does not close

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to achieve is to change the name of the btn when opening and closing, however, when I test the functions individually it works fine however when I combine both function in one btn it doesn't could someone help, please.

What I am trying to achieve is to change the name of the btn when opening and closing, however, when I test the functions individually it works fine however when I combine both function in one btn it doesn't could someone help, please.

```js
// JavaScript Document
let myBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let myBase = document.querySelector("#base");
let status = false;

myBase.style.marginTop = "-250px";

function myFunction() {

  if (status === false) {
    myBase.style.marginTop = "-120px";
    status = true;
  } else if (status = true) {
    myBase.style.marginTop = "-250px"
    status = false;
  }
}

//myBtn.onclick = myFunction;

myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>OPEN</P>";

function nameFunction() {

  if (status === false) {
    myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>OPEN</P>";
    status = true;
  } else if (status = true) {
    myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>CLOSE</P>";
    status = false;
  }
}


// myBtn.onclick = nameFunction;


function twoFunction() {

  myFunction();
  nameFunction();
}


myBtn.onclick = twoFunction;
```

```css
#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#base {
  padding: 10px;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#base>div {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>


<body>

  <div id="btn">
    <p>OPEN</p>
  </div>

  <div id="base">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: `(status = true)` a single `=` is for assignment. Use `==` or `===` for equality check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems with the code:

1. `if (status = true)` will perform *assignment*, not equality check.

   - You should use `==` or `===` for that. Although since you're checking a boolean, you don't need an `else if` - if `status` is not `false`, then it can only be `true`. You can just do

```
if (status === false) {
  /* ... code if false ... */
} else  {
  /* ... code if true ... */
}
```

2. You set `status = false` and `status = true` twice. First in `myFunction`, then in `nameFunction`. So when you the handler is invoked `myFunction` checks the status, sees `status` is `false` switches it to `true` and then when `nameFunction` runs, `status` is now `true`, where it should have been `false`.

   - you can extract the code to change the `status` value and only call it from one place. I moved it to `twoFunction` after both other functions have completed:

```js
// JavaScript Document
let myBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let myBase = document.querySelector("#base");
let status = false;

myBase.style.marginTop = "-250px";

function myFunction() {
console.log(status)
  if (status === false) {
    myBase.style.marginTop = "-120px";
  } else { //no need for else if
    myBase.style.marginTop = "-250px"
  }
}

//myBtn.onclick = myFunction;

myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>OPEN</P>";

function nameFunction() {

  if (status === false) {
    myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>OPEN</P>";
  } else { //no need for else if
    myBtn.innerHTML = "<P>CLOSE</P>";
  }
}

// myBtn.onclick = nameFunction;

function twoFunction() {
  myFunction();
  nameFunction();

  //only set the status once
  if (status === false) {
    status = true;
  } else {
    status = false;
  }
}


myBtn.onclick = twoFunction;
```

```css
#btn {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: orange;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#base {
  padding: 10px;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#base>div {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="btn">
    <p>OPEN</p>
  </div>

  <div id="base">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello VLAZ - Thank you so much for your assistance and to tell you the fact you made my day very easy and my sincere appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `else if (status = true)` should be `else if (status == true)` or `else if (status === true)`